# Print out a certain section of a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I could be going about this the wrong way and if so, I'd appreciate a different way at looking at solving the problem, but here is what I am trying to do, and how I'm attempting to do it.

I am making a simple address-book based on some beginner project suggestions I found and I'm slowly implementing it, but I cannot figure how to get it to search for a certain section of the file. I want it to print the name, address, phone and mobile. All of which are on a separate line, 4 lines total.

I'm using the following code to accomplish this:

```
def search_entries():
    found = 0
    search = raw_input("Please enter the person's name: ")
    for line in open('addbook.txt', 'r').readlines():
        if search in line:
            found = 1
        if found >= 1:
            print line
            if found == 4: break
```

However, instead of printing just printing those 4 lines from the person's name it prints the rest of the file. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You always set `found` to 1 so it never reaches 4. You probably meant to write `found += 1` instead of `found = 1`...

Comment: Thanks for that, feel a bit silly now. Don't know how I missed it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that I forgot to add a counter to the code:

```
def search_entries():
    found = 0
    search = raw_input("Please enter the person's name: ")
    for line in open('addbook.txt', 'r').readlines():
        if search in line:
            found = 1
        if found >= 1:
            print line
            found = found + 1
            if found == 4: break
```

Comment: You should edit your original question, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`found` never changes after being set to 1.

Comment: Thanks! Just realised straight after I posted :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a slightly better way of writing this (un-tested):

```
from itertools import islice

with open('input.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if 'bob' in line:
            next_3 = list(islice(fin, 3))
            print line, next_3
            break
```